# Why would adding a simple field to select change the amount of returned rows SQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a more complicated problem that I have tried to isolate down to it's components.

I have a simple query that returns all distinct customer emails (So every individual customer)

```
Select distinct 
CustomerEmail

FROM [JMNYC-AMTDB].[AMTPLUS].[dbo].Invoices I (nolock) --I don't think the tables are relevant to the problem. 
                LEFT JOIN (SELECT 
                                ID.Company_Code
                                ,ID.Division_Code
                                ,ID.Invoice_Number
                                ,SUM (ID.Price* ID.Quantity) Total
                            FROM [JMNYC-AMTDB].[AMTPLUS].[dbo].Invoices_Detail ID (nolock)
                            GROUP BY ID.Company_Code, ID.Division_Code, ID.Invoice_Number) ID 
                        ON I.Company_Code = ID.Company_Code
                        AND I.Division_Code = ID.Division_Code
                        AND I.Invoice_Number = ID.Invoice_Number
                LEFT JOIN 
                    [JMDNJ-ACCELSQL].[A1WAREHOUSE].[dbo].SHIPHIST SH (nolock) ON I.Pickticket_Number = SH.Packslip
                LEFT JOIN 
                    [JMDNJ-ACCELSQL].[A1WAREHOUSE].[dbo].[SpraygroundMagentoCustomerEmailData] S on SH.CUST_PO = S.InvoiceNumber

Where I.Company_Code ='09' AND I.Division_Code = '001'
AND I.Customer_Number = 'ECOM2X'
AND ISNUMERIC(SH.CUST_PO) <> 0 
AND I.Date_Created BETWEEN DATEADD(month, -0, '6/1/2016') AND '1/1/2017'  -- Orders Base default is 12 months, options are 6,12, 18, and 24
```

This returns 19,516 rows.

If however, I add a second simple select statement to my query,

```
Select distinct 
Month(I.Date_Created) Month,
CustomerEmail
FROM [JMNYC-AMTDB].[AMTPLUS].[dbo].Invoices I (nolock)...
```

It now returns 20,452 rows.

Writing this question out, I think I understood the problem. It will duplicate the emails for different months. So if a customer placed an order on June and July, his email will appear twice, once for month 6 and once for month 7.

So this number should be more correct than the 19,516 number, right?

The way I calculate the TotalCustomers Number later in my more complex query is a simple Dense Rank statement

```
,DENSE_RANK() over (order by CustomerEmail asc) 
+DENSE_RANK() over (order by CustomerEmail desc) 
- 1 as TotalCustomersOverRange
```

This returns me 19,516 because it doesn't count multiple purchases. But this is also technically correct, because over that date range, there are less unique customers. Only when you break it out by month do you get duplicate customers who are really them same.

What is the best way to fix this? Here is my full query:

```
--Calculate average amount of time between purchase
--Calculate percentage of quantity and total increase with each purchase.
--Return most valued customers.  
--User defined base range
-- later on, more refined user defined customer base, so if the base range is 18 months and the customer range is 1 month, it will only check the data against customers that purchased orders within the last month. 
-- over the customer range, we define who the customers are. We call this RANGE
-- over the orderes base range,  we define and how many times they ordered. We call this BASE.
-- First we filter by month, returning total new orders and total recurring orders
-- (FOR OTHER REPORT, filter by state and not month)
-- Then within the month, we drill down to calculate how many customers are one orders, two orders, three orders, etc total
-- For each order amount, we calculate average days between orders, total value, lifetime value, and quantity changes


SELECT DISTINCT --*
Month

,(DENSE_RANK() over (partition by Month order by CustomerEmail asc)
    +DENSE_RANK() over (partition by Month order by CustomerEmail desc))
    -1 as TotalCustomersThisMonth

,Sum(Case When AmountOrdersOverRangeByCustomer = 1 and RangeOrderNumber = 1 then 1 else 0 end) over (partition by Month) NewCustomersOverRangeThisMonth --Some of those customers aren't really new, if we expand to the base.
,Sum(Case When AmountOrdersOverRangeByCustomer = 1 and AmountOrdersOverBaseByCustomer = 1 then 1 else 0 end) over (partition by Month) NewCustomersOverBaseThisMonth
,Sum(Case When AmountOrdersOverRangeByCustomer = 1 and AmountOrdersOverBaseByCustomer > 1 then 1 else 0 end)  over (partition by Month) RecurringCustomersOverBaseButNewInRangeThisMonth -- Customers in Base who are not in range.
,Sum(Case When AmountOrdersOverRangeByCustomer > 1 and RangeOrderNumber =1 then 1 else 0 end)  over (partition by Month) RecurringCustomerOverRangeThisMonth
,TTT.NewCustomersOverRange
,TTT.NewCustomersOverBase
,TTT.RecurringCustomersOverBaseButNewInRange
,TTT.RecurringCustomerOverRange
,TTT.TotalCustomersOverBase
,TTT.TotalCustomersOverRange

FROM --This table calculates new and recurring customers.
(
    SELECT  
    *
    ,Sum(Case When AmountOrdersOverRangeByCustomer = 1 and RangeOrderNumber = 1 then 1 else 0 end) over () NewCustomersOverRange --Some of those customers aren't really new, if we expand to the base.
    ,Sum(Case When AmountOrdersOverRangeByCustomer = 1 and AmountOrdersOverBaseByCustomer = 1 then 1 else 0 end) over () NewCustomersOverBase 
    ,Sum(Case When AmountOrdersOverRangeByCustomer = 1 and AmountOrdersOverBaseByCustomer > 1 then 1 else 0 end)  over () RecurringCustomersOverBaseButNewInRange -- Customers in Base who are not in range
    ,Sum(Case When AmountOrdersOverRangeByCustomer > 1 and RangeOrderNumber =1 then 1 else 0 end)  over () RecurringCustomerOverRange

    FROM -- This table gives you Order Numbers Per Customer
    (
        SELECT 
            *
            ,ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by CustomerEmail order by Date_Created asc) RangeOrderNumber

            ,(DENSE_RANK() over (partition by CustomerEmail order by Date_Created asc)
            +DENSE_RANK() over (partition by CustomerEmail order by Date_Created desc))
            -1 as AmountOrdersOverRangeByCustomer

            ,Max(BaseOrderNumber) over (partition by CustomerEmail) AmountOrdersOverBaseByCustomer

            ,DENSE_RANK() over (order by CustomerEmail asc) 
            +DENSE_RANK() over (order by CustomerEmail desc) 
            - 1 as TotalCustomersOverRange

        FROM --This table gives you a line by line basis of every order
        (
            Select 
             I.Date_Created
            ,I.Company_Code
            ,I.Division_Code
            ,I.Invoice_Number
            ,Sh.CUST_PO
            ,I.Total_Quantity
            ,ID.Total
            ,SH.Ship_City City
            ,CASE WHEN SH.Ship_Cntry <> 'US' THEN 'INT' ELSE SH.Ship_prov END State
            ,SH.Ship_Zip Zip
            ,SH.Ship_Cntry Country
            ,Month(I.Date_Created) Month
            ,S.CustomerEmail
            ,Count(*) over (partition by CustomerEmail order by Date_Created asc) BaseOrderNumber

            ,dense_rank() over (order by CustomerEmail) 
            + dense_rank() over (order by CustomerEmail desc) 
            - 1 as TotalCustomersOverBase
            --,Count(Distinct CustomerEmail) over () as TotalCustomersOverBase
            --,ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by S.CustomerEmail order by Date_Created asc) PurchaseCount --this goes somewhere else

            --,(DENSE_RANK() over (partition by Month(I.Date_Created) order by CustomerEmail asc)
            --+DENSE_RANK() over (partition by Month(I.Date_Created) order by CustomerEmail desc))
            ---1 as TotalCustomersThisMonth

            FROM [JMNYC-AMTDB].[AMTPLUS].[dbo].Invoices I (nolock)
                LEFT JOIN (SELECT 
                                ID.Company_Code
                                ,ID.Division_Code
                                ,ID.Invoice_Number
                                ,SUM (ID.Price* ID.Quantity) Total
                            FROM [JMNYC-AMTDB].[AMTPLUS].[dbo].Invoices_Detail ID (nolock)
                            GROUP BY ID.Company_Code, ID.Division_Code, ID.Invoice_Number) ID 
                        ON I.Company_Code = ID.Company_Code
                        AND I.Division_Code = ID.Division_Code
                        AND I.Invoice_Number = ID.Invoice_Number
                LEFT JOIN 
                    [JMDNJ-ACCELSQL].[A1WAREHOUSE].[dbo].SHIPHIST SH (nolock) ON I.Pickticket_Number = SH.Packslip
                LEFT JOIN 
                    [JMDNJ-ACCELSQL].[A1WAREHOUSE].[dbo].[SpraygroundMagentoCustomerEmailData] S on SH.CUST_PO = S.InvoiceNumber

            Where I.Company_Code ='09' AND I.Division_Code = '001'
            AND I.Customer_Number = 'ECOM2X'
            AND ISNUMERIC(SH.CUST_PO) <> 0 
            AND I.Date_Created BETWEEN DATEADD(month, -12, '1/1/2017') AND '12/31/2016'  -- Orders Base default is 12 months, options are 6,12, 18, and 24
            --AND CustomerEmail is NULL
        )T
        Where  T.Date_Created BETWEEN '6/1/2016' AND '1/1/2017'-- Customer Range
    )TT

    --
    --Order By CustomerEmail, RangeOrderNumber asc 
    --

)TTT

--Order By Date_Created desc 
--Order By CustomerEmail, RangeOrderNumber asc 
Order By Month
```

Comment: Just adding a field to a select generally _can't_ alter the result set or number of rows returned.

Comment: But when that `SELECT` has `DISTINCT` it can, and will, make a big difference @TimBiegeleisen. :) `DISTINCT` does exactly what it says on the tin, Natan. If you have more columns, you are going to have more **distinct** values.

Comment: I think you're looking for `COUNT(CustomerEmail) over (partition by Month)`...

Answer (score 2):

When using the `DISTINCT` operator, the dataset returned will only contain **distinct** rows. That means that if 2 or more rows that contain the same values for every column that row will only be returned once.

In your first statement you only display the value for `CustomerEmail`, so you will get a dataset for every distinct/unique value of `CustomerEmail`.

In the second statment, you have `Month(I.Date_Created)` and `CustomerEmail`, so you will get a row for every distinct/unique value of those 2 values **combined**. This means that in your first dataset that was more than 1 row with a specific value for `CustomerEmail`, and when you added `Month(I.Date_Created)` there were (at least) 2 different value for that expression.

In very simple terms, take the statement below:

```
WITH N AS(
    SELECT *
    FROM (VALUES(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL)) N (N)),
Tally AS(
    SELECT LEFT(NEWID(),1) AS C,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS I
    FROM N N1, N N2, N N3, N N4, N N5)
SELECT DISTINCT C
FROM Tally;
```

Despite the tally table creating 100,000 rows, you probably only received a dataset of 16 rows. Now, let's add both columns to the `DISTINCT`:

```
WITH N AS(
    SELECT *
    FROM (VALUES(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL)) N (N)),
Tally AS(
    SELECT LEFT(NEWID(),1) AS C,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS I
    FROM N N1, N N2, N N3, N N4, N N5)
SELECT DISTINCT C,I
FROM Tally;
```

Now you get 100,000 rows, despite the fact that the underlying data hasn't changed (well, it has as new values for `NEWID` would have been generated, but for the purposes of the example it works).